# Python UnicodeEncodeError: codec can't encode character

Tags: python, windows, unicode, python-unicode

I created an executable file from my python script (checkData.py)

I'm trying to pass string data, which includes locale characters, to this exe file from another python script something like below:

```
...
dataPath = easygui.fileopenbox(msg, title)
p= subprocess.Popen(["checkData.exe",  dataPath], stdout = subprocess.PIPE )
```

When I print `dataPath` from caller script I can see the locale characters.
When I tried to print the string passed to exe file I got an error.

```
...
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("directory", action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.directory)
```

Here is my error message:

```
C:\script\build\exe.win32-3.2>checkSi‌​mTestData.exe
  dataDirectoryPath= C:\samples\şample_test_data 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py",
    line 27, in <module> exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "checkData.py",
    line 56, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.2\lib\encodings\cp1254.py",
    line 19, in encode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfe'
  in position 80: character maps to <undefined> –
```

When I run below command:

```
sys.stdout.encoding
```

I got "cp1254"

Could you help me please?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It's apparently Windows.

Comment: I agree, but which one?  And for that matter, which Python?

Comment: It's Python 3.2, which is obvious from the traceback. It looks to me like you're storing cp1254 bytes in a `str` object instead of decoding them to unicode into the string object, but probably not in the code you've actually included.

Comment: Is your script working when you run: ``python checkData.py "some string with your locale characters"``?

Comment: John, I'm using windows xp and Python32

Comment: Robert, I'll tell it in a few minute

Comment: python checkData.py "some string with my locale characters" is running. But when I try checkData.exe "some locale characters" it gives same error.

Comment: at the case of command prompt failure especially on windoze!!! first try to write your output to a file

Comment: I wrote to output to a file. The output like this b'c:\\samples\\\\xfample_test_data'